# source a script into multiple r instances simultaneously

Tags: r, multithreading, batch-file, cmd

I have a script which has a for loop doing some analysis on a data-set. If I break my data into 10 parts and run analysis in 10 separate R instances then it takes 10x less time. I want to do this using batch. Basically I want to source a R script into many different R instances simultaneously using cmd.

Comment: There are better possibilities for parallelization. Have a look at the `foreach` package and its parallel backends.

Comment: R is its own scripting language.  Not understanding how you want to integrate this with a .bat file.